# What is the difference of these two sentences?

Tags: sentence

Please explain the difference of these sentences....

1) The garden is not as large as yours.

2) The garden is not larger than yours.

I feel these are same. But is there difference? Please teach me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sentence (2) allows for the possibility that the two gardens are of the same size; sentence (1) does not.